# Shapes3d from Tensorflow not allowing test in split

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-datasets

I copied this part of the code straight from tensorflow's example, but it's not allowing the split. Does anyone know why?

[image]

I've tried many different split options, but I just keep getting this error every time I put test in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try this, may be you shall be using the old version of tensorflow_datasets but if not then try this method.... builder = tfds.builder('shapes3d')
ds = builder.as_dataset(split=['test' , 'train[:20%]' , 'train[20%:]'])

Answer (score 0):

The [shapes3d](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/shapes3d) dataset only contains one split, which is `train`. You are passing "test" as a split element hence raising the error. It also does not support supervised structures. Please try as follows

```
train_data,test_data,valid_data = tfds.load("shapes3d",split=["train[20%:80%]","train[:20%]","train[80%:]"])
```

If `with_info = True`, `tfds.load` will return the tuple `(tf.data.Dataset, tfds.core.DatasetInfo)`, the latter containing the info associated with the builder.  Thank you!

```
(train_data,test_data,valid_data),data_info = tfds.load("shapes3d",split=["train[20%:80%]","train[:20%]","train[80%:]"],with_info=True)
```